# Potential immunization against airborn viruses

Tags: immunology, virology

I have had an idea based on the principals of a virus and their properties and how they enter the cell by tricking it into believing it is a protein etc.

If we coated a copper particle (or another type of metal which should neutralize the atomic structure) and utilize the process they use to induct themself into our cells by mimicing the methods they connect by, would ejecting it in an aerosol steralize the earth from that specific airborn virus?

My ideology seems to fit that if we don't immunize the atmosphere against viruses that they will always naturally occur due to the Entropic nature of the universe. Does this fit into current medical science?

Comment: A lot of airborne viruses enter through sialic acid receptors. If someone can make a spray that blocks those, viruses will have no receptors available to bind. It's similar to closing unused ports or banning incoming connections on a computer network interface to prevent hack attacks and block self-replicating malware. I'm surprised there aren't known examples of cells that retract or alter/randomize the shape of commonly infected receptors when they aren't in use.

Comment: Could you clarify what precisely do you want to coat the particles with. Ligand molecules to block the cell receptors or receptor molecules to "mop up" the viruses?